# Field attributes in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I use dozens of attributes in my classes and they are basically always the same. Like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string a;

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string b;

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string c;

    [JsonProperty("slightly different", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string different;
}
```

Is it possible to create a shortcut for this? So that I don't need to write this entire line: `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]`.

`JsonProperty` comes from Json.NET and is sealed :)

Comment: You can create your own attribute inheriting JsonProperty and see if it works; but my bet is no, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find you are setting `NullValueHandling` to `Ignore` on every property, you could just set it in `JsonSerializerSettings` instead.  Then you would not need to apply individual attributes to your properties at all (except where the JSON property name differs from the class property name).

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};
```

Your class definition would then look like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string a;
    public string b;
    public string c;

    [JsonProperty("slightly different")]
    public string different;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a snippet in Visual Studio.

Snippets are a handy way to quickly add blocks of frequently used blocks of code into your source. Studio has a few snippets available by default like 'cw' translating into Console.WriteLine(); or foreach and for creating loop constructs with brackets. 
See an example of how to create a snippet here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Comment: A little more detail would be useful. What is a snippet? How does one create a snippet? How does one invoke a snippet?

Comment: Sorry mate. Snippets are kind of shortcuts for frequently used blocks of text. Here's a walkthrough from MS on how to create one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Comment: Update your answer, don't just put it in a comment. And you should summarize the directions instead of relying on an external link, which could break.